# Entity is not rendering properly in my game

Tags: java, rendering, comparator, game-development

Recently, I have been developing a game(I am a beginner, but it is organized).
My problem is that I have added a tree(Static Entity) in my game and I have made an entity manager to render it properly by using a comparator.The code for it can be seen below.

```
public class EntityManager {

    private Handler handler;
    private Player player;
    private ArrayList<Entity> entities;
    private Comparator<Entity> renderSorter = new Comparator<Entity>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(Entity a, Entity b) {
            if(a.getY() + a.getHeight() < b.getY() + b.getHeight()) { 
                return -1;
            }
            return 1;
        }
        
    };
    
    public EntityManager(Handler handler, Player player) {
        this.handler = handler;
        this.player = player;
        entities = new ArrayList<Entity>();
        addEntity(player);
    }
        
    public void tick() {
        Iterator<Entity> it = entities.iterator();
        
        while(it.hasNext()) {
            Entity e = it.next();
            e.tick();
            //if(!e.active)
                //it.remove();
        }
        entities.sort(renderSorter);
    }
        
    public void render(Graphics g) {
        for(Entity e : entities) {
            e.render(g);
        }
        //player.postRender(g);
    }
    
    public void addEntity(Entity e) {
        entities.add(e);
    }
```

Although the tree is rendering properly like this[Tree rendering behind the player](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTt3R.png)

But a new entity that I added (a Rock) is not rendering properly, like this[rock rendering in front of player](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIaBl.png)

I don't know why this is happening , or if this is a bug.
if you want any other details, or source code then please tell.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no problem in the magnitude of which your code is organized.
Here the problem is in the compare function because:

```
tree height + tree y > player height + player y
```

But as the rock is smaller than the player, it will be placed in front because you involve the height of the object so it gives this:

```
rock y < player y
```

but

```
rock height + rock y> player height + player y
```